# Aliens selling household appliances?

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I'm looking for a sci-fi book's title. It was a novel about aliens (Martians I think) who came to Earth not to conquer it militarily, but economically. They sold household appliances at lower prices. It was published after 2010 for sure.

Comment: If you can visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and [edit] more details in your question, it would help immensely.

Comment: Sounds like something Philip Dick would have done: Fnools turn up as tiny real-estate agents and VW repair men in "War with the Fnools"

Comment: Possibly the same story asked about in [Short story about a Martian invasion that starts with a mysterious set of stores in major cities](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230763/short-story-about-a-martian-invasion-that-starts-with-a-mysterious-set-of-stores) i.e. [The Martian Shop by Howard Fast](http://www.writing.upenn.edu/~afilreis/50s/fast-martian-shop.html).

Comment: Maybe  2001 novel "First Contract" by Greg Costikyan?

Comment: @Yorik - no, it wasn't him.
JohnRennie - I wrote it's a novel, not a short story. 
JimGreen - no, it was published after 2010 for sure.

Answer (score 4):

**Ring Around the Sun** by Clifford Simak comes close; there's
a bunch of 'forever' products coming onto the market, at unbeatable
prices, and... it's not Martians, but another kind of alien.
Alas, 'published after 2010' doesn't fit; first edition was 1952.

Comment: Another Simak novel, *They Walked like Men* (1962), also has aliens taking over the world with money: buying homes and evicting residents; buying factories and stores and closing them, etc.  Because of course only aliens would do that sort of thing...

Comment: Thank you for help, but I just found it - 'Trzeci najazd Marsjan' by Marek Oramus. You could never guess because... it was not published in English. I did not know that it was a Polish novel (I'm from Poland). Simak's novels seem interesting too.

Comment: In English it would be called something like "The Third Martian Raid", right?

Comment: @Sprytus you can add your own answer to identify the book. That way we have a permanent record of it.

Answer (score 1):

Per the OP's comment on another answer, this is *Trzeci najazd Marsjan* (2010), a novel written in Polish by [Marek Oramus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marek_Oramus) ([Polish version](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marek_Oramus)).