# Short story from a 1970s era collection about aliens clandestinely selling perfect tech on Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

It was in a sci fi collection, probably from the 1970s.

It's about a main character who is trying to figure out how another person has such perfect things from a brand name "P" (for perfect, but the main character doesn't know that at first).

It turns out that the products are sold by aliens whose knees don't bend at the right place to pass as human. There is a TV that has no lines in its display and coffee that tastes the way it smells.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like "A Full Member of the Club" by Bob Shaw. This story [has come up before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223100/lighter-lighting-from-a-pool-coffee-that-tastes-just-like-it-smells) and you can read it here: https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v35n07_1974-07/page/n49/mode/2up

Comment: Oh, yes, I answered that one. Michael, it does sound like a duplicate of the previous question. Please let us know if the answer is *A Full Member of the Club* and if so we'll mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: There are at least two other IMHO correct story-id answers here on that (one by me in 2018) but unaccepted. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/189067/28516 https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/193461/28516

Comment: Yes! That's the one. We can mark this as duplicate or answer it here and I'll accept it